# Leveraging the wordpress API in an android reader app

Tags: java, android, wordpress

I'm writing an android magazine reader for a campus publication I work for. We use wordpress to publish our website, and I want to leverage the wordpress REST API to pull stories (posts) directly from the website, without publishers having to take any additional steps to publish posts on the app after publishing them on the site. I'll do this by getting JSON objects representing posts and deserializing them into POJOs of the Story class (defined in the android application), around which views will then be built dynamically.

I've just discovered the Wordpress REST API and am really excited because I think that the implementation as described above is going to be pretty simple. Are there any obvious roadblocks that I'm missing that might complicate things?

I know that the API responds with a "content" parameter that is a string containing the HTML code for the post, with references to included images/media in the appropriate places. How can I get Android to load that html and display it properly in a WebViewer?

Comment: The Wordpress API seems to work well and is pretty stable, you shouldn't have any problems. We [published](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appsropos.instapress) a Wordpress reader for Android recently, drop me a line if you run into coding issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to parse the html and separately load images and other resources, simply use
[`loadDataWithBaseURL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) like so:

```
WebView storyView = (WebView) findViewById( .... );
String htmlToDisplay = ....;
storyView.loadDataWithBaseURL( "http://storysite.com/', htmlToDisplay, mimeType, encoding, "" );
```

The baseURL will be prepended to all relative partial URIs found in the document, so that the WebView can take care of loading all other assets for you.